# Get sum for each group in group by query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MYSQL and 
I have following data in database...

It is a group by query as

```
select year, country , product,SUM(profit) 
from table 
group by year, country , product;
```

```
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
| year | country | product    | SUM(profit) |
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
| 2000 | Finland | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2000 | Finland | Phone      |         100 |
| 2000 | India   | Calculator |         150 |
| 2000 | India   | Computer   |        1200 |
| 2000 | USA     | Calculator |          75 |
| 2000 | USA     | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2001 | Finland | Phone      |          10 |
| 2001 | USA     | Calculator |          50 |
| 2001 | USA     | Computer   |        2700 |
| 2001 | USA     | TV         |         250 |
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
```

What should be the query if I want to take the data as shown below:

```
+------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| year |SUM(profit)|country |SUM(profit)| product    | SUM(profit) |
+------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 2000 | 4525      |Finland |1600       | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2000 | 4525      |Finland |1600       | Phone      |         100 |
| 2000 | 4525      |India   |1350       | Calculator |         150 |
| 2000 | 4525      |India   |1350       | Computer   |        1200 |
| 2000 | 4525      |USA     |1575       | Calculator |          75 |
| 2000 | 4525      |USA     |1575       | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2001 | 3010      |Finland |10         | Phone      |          10 |
| 2001 | 3010      |USA     |3000       | Calculator |          50 |
| 2001 | 3010      |USA     |3000       | Computer   |        2700 |
| 2001 | 3010      |USA     |3000       | TV         |         250 |
+------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+--------------|
```

Actually I want to get sum for each group...

Comment: You want mysql and oracle solutions? (regarding your tags)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  These are two different databases.

Comment: @wumpz i ma using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    data.*,
    d2.country_sum,
    d3.year_sum
from 
    (select year, country , product,SUM(profit) 
     from table t1
     group by year, country , product) data 
      JOIN
        (select year, country,SUM(profit) as country_sum
         from table t1
         group by year, country ) d2 ON data.year=d2.year and data.country=d2.country
      JOIN
        (select year, SUM(profit) as year_sum
         from table t1
         group by year) d3 ON data.year=d2.year
```

And reorder the fields as you need

Answer (score 1):

In oracle/SQL server the following will work:

```
select year, 
sum(sum(profit)) over (partition by year) as YearProfit,
country, 
sum(sum(profit)) over (partition by year, country) as CountryProfit,
product, 
sum(sum(profit)) over (partition by year, country, product) as ProductProfit
from [table]
group by year, country, product
```